# Deleted terms are not getting reflected on list in managed metadata column

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata, term

I have managed metadata column in one of my SharePoint list. **I deleted one term from term store management settings but the changes are not getting reflected on the list items**. term is still present in managed metadata column in list item.

Now, When I try to update any item it shows term value in managed metadata column in RED colour and I am unable to update the record because the term is already deleted from term set but it is still referred on existing record from somewhere.

I also deleted the term from "**TaxonomyHiddenList**" but still the same problem.

I wanted to avoid updating every record and delete the term using custom code.

**(Note: List has already crossed the threshold limit)**

Antbody please suggest me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer** - You cannot avoid updating every item to clear values, because each item holds previously saved term values and displays them if requested.

You can confirm this behaviour by requesting data from specific item via PowerShell or REST API.

In normal conditions, before displaying (in views, forms, search results etc) *SharePoint* is checking if terms have been merged and renamed to adjust display value based on *TaxonomyHiddenList* (after sync to this list has occurred) or *TermStore*. In this case, all entries in *TermStore* and *TaxonomyHiddenList* are cleared, so nothing is left to check and You see value what is stored in the field.

Answer (score 0):

When a term is eliminated, a reference remains in the lists and libraries, it is not updated neither in views nor in forms